# Nest JS Exception Overrides Pipe Implementation in all levels both global and local

Tags: javascript, web, nestjs, httpbackend

[click to see code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFZS.png)

I am implementing validation in my nestjs project and i implemented Http Exception Handler on the global scope previously . Then i Used the ValidationPipe class for input validation but its gets overridden by exception filter each time a validation fails. and works just fine once i comment excepton filter

Comment: Could you show some code? What you have bound, what your filters look like, etc?

Comment: check image ..  i want to use pipes to return the error object in the response

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.**

Comment: Why are you binding two `ValidationPipe`s?

Answer (score 0):

Exception filter throw validation exception if occur. It is just that you are not handling/catching exception details.
Try to fill response.Status object correctly in your exception filter class to capture exception details correctly.

```
    export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
      catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const status = exception.getStatus();
    
        const message = exception.message;
    
          response.status(status).json({statusCode: status,
          timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
          path: request.url,
          message: exception.message   // this one give you your validation error msg
        });
      }
    }
```